# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : Razor asp-page link problem in project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project and want to add some Razor pages to it. Based on another post on SO I added this to the `programs.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

...

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
```

I also created a `Pages` folder and put a razor page inside it with a folder called `Schedules`.

My structure is like this:

```
Project > Pages > Schedules
```

In the `Pages` folder, I have a page with a link like this

```
<a asp-page="/Schedules/DailySchedule">Daily Schedule</a>
```

For some reason that link doesn't even show up as a link. It does show as plain text but not as a link. I can add a link like this

```
<a href="Schedules/DailySchedule">Daily Schedule</a>
```

But in all the samples I have looked at using `asp-page` should work. Did I miss an important step?

Comment: If the route is not resolved, the asp-page anchor tag helper does not render a valid href link.  You will need to also share the code for the cshtml.cs (code behind for the razor page) to further troubleshoot.  Helpful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @AdamVincent there is no code behind in my razor page. Right now, it is just a razor page with a single link <a asp-page="/Schedules/DailySchedule">Daily Schedule</a>. I suspect, as you said, the route isn't being resolved. I just checked and the link works from the _layout page in Views>Shared folder but not on any page in the Pages folder. Do I need a Shared\_layout in each directory? I am going to try that now.

Comment: The link works now after adding the Shared folder with its own _Layout.cshtml _validationScriptsPartial.cshtml to the Pages directory as well as the _ViewImports.cshtml and _viewStart.cshtml. I am not sure which file fixed it but it does work now.

Comment: No, you do not need layout per 'folder'.  I'm not sure even how you got it working by doing this, and I would propose that this will just cause more confusion down the road unless you backtrack this 'work-around'. You say you don't have a code-behind, but you must.  A razor page is a CSHTML file and an CSHTML.CS file, with a class which derives from `PageModel` As you are just starting, I would suggest trying some of the things in the Introduction to Razor Pages link I provided.

Comment: @AdamVincent Actually, you don't have to have a PageModel class. It's perfectly possible (though not recommended) to create a _.cshtml_ file, put an `@page` directive at the top and declare fields, properties and handler methods in an `@functions` block within that file.

Comment: @MikeBrind Actually, a `@functions` or `@code` block is for Razor *components*. Not Razor Pages.

Comment: @AdamVincent `@functions` was first introduced in ASP.NET Web Pages in 2010 along with the introduction of the Razor syntax, and retained in Razor Pages. It was also ported across to Razor Components but use of  `@code` has pretty much replaced it there. Try what I suggested - you'll see it works.

Comment: I know it works. I can see clearly that a cshtml with no code behind still generates a class deriving from `Page` but it doesn't match up with any of the *current* guidance in the introduction to razor pages, view components, razor components, or Blazor.  Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. There are a lot of facets to ASP.NET, and they all share about 80% of the same backend code.  We know this. New users of ASP.NET do not. There is no benefit to straying from the docs and confusing them.

Comment: @AdamVincent Fair enough. It's just that I didn't think you knew that, based on your earlier comments. And in fairness to me, I did also point out that this approach is not recommended should any new user read my comment.